# Asp.net display server event log messages in a readable format inside a grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have the following lines of code which will fetch the event logs from the remote server. Here i could able get the even log info from the properties InstanceId and Message. But how can i read and display the event log details in a user-friendly manner something like this. I can simply loop through eventlogentry list and read the eventlog message. But how to format the event log message.
[image]

The EventLog message is something like this
[image]
And this format is changing based on the event id. However i want to display only specific event ids data(4727, 4728, 4729, 4730, 4731, 4732, 4733, 4734, 4735, 4737, 4754, 4755, 4756, 4757). How to format this eventlog message.
And my piece of code is here.

```
EventLog log = new EventLog(logName, machineName, source);
                        EventLogEntryCollection col = log.Entries;

                        List<EventLogEntry> lstEventLogEntry = col.Cast<EventLogEntry>().ToList<EventLogEntry>().FindAll(x => (x.TimeGenerated >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2)));
                        foreach (EventLogEntry ev in lstEventLogEntry)
                        {
                            //Read thid Event log data and show in the gridview     
                            long id = ev.InstanceId;
                            string message = ev.Message;
                            string mchineName = ev.MachineName;
                            DateTime timeGenerated = ev.TimeGenerated;
                        }
```

Comment: You can use `RowDataBound` to format it. Just set the list as `DataSource` and cast `e.Row.DataItem` to `EventLogEntry` to get the entries.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, I have updated the question. Please have a look.